# Button doesn't load the component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to do a 'buy' `Button` that when pressed I get an object (which I managed to do)
and display a small component that has the buying options and change the url to be `'/buy'`.
I tried to do on the `button href='/buy'`  but it sends me to a new page.
and it doesn't even show the component that I made (for now a blue rectangle)
the way component work is a `Class Component that gets data, and sends methods too -> Functional Component that draws the cards (inside of it there is the`buy`button, that should call the method from it's father class the onBuyClicked method.)`

the `BuyComponent` code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
```

import './buy.component.scss'

```
export default class BuyComponent extends Component {

render() {
    return(
        <div id="buyComponentTesting"> Hello world </div>
        )
    }
}
```

the Class that has the button:    *(// this is just the button part*)

```
const FunctionalProductCardComponent = props => {
return (
    // giving the div id only for design pourpse
    <div id="ProductCard">
        <Router>
        <Col>
                    <Button   href="/buy" to="/buy"  onClick={ (newProduct) => {props.onClick(() => {return newProduct={
                            id: props.product._id,
                            price: props.product.price,
                            serial: props.product.serial,
                            size: chosenSize,
                            color: chosenColor,
                    }} ) } } >Buy</Button>

        </Col>
            </Router>
    </div>
)
}

export default FunctionalProductCardComponent;
```

the handling of the onClick:

```
   onBuyClicked = (e) => {
    console.log(e())
    alert("wee woo from pr")
    return(
        <BuyComponent/>
    )
}
```

the wanted component css:

```
#buyComponentTesting{
background-color: blue;
z-index: 10;
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
margin: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by using **Link** from **'react-router-dom'**.

```
import {Link, Route} from 'react-router-dom'
```

Eg:

```
<Router>
    <Route path='/buy' component={BuyComponent} />
    <Col>
        <Link to='/buy'>
                <Button onClick={(newProduct) => {props.onClick(() => {return newProduct={
                        id: props.product._id,
                        price: props.product.price,
                        serial: props.product.serial,
                        size: chosenSize,
                        color: chosenColor,
                }} ) } } >Buy</Button>
        </Link>
    </Col>
</Router>
```

Comment: it displays the component but moves the cards from it's place, do you know how can I make it 'float' above the other components? so it doesn't move anything from it's place?